# How do I mock an ActiveRecord object in Yii?

Tags: php, unit-testing, yii

In Yii I want to perform some unit tests on a class that uses ActiveRecord objects. For example, I have a Translation ActiveRecord. When I try to create a mock object for it I get an error.

In my test I have the line:

```
$translation = $this->getMock("Translation");
```

And then I get this error when I run my test:

```
PHPUnit 3.7.30 by Sebastian Bergmann.

Configuration read from /Users/riverstyx/Sites/protected/tests/phpunit.xml

E.

Time: 1.27 seconds, Memory: 6.25Mb

There was 1 error:

1) TranslationManagerTest::testCreateNewTranslation
Trying to get property of non-object

/Users/riverstyx/yii/framework/db/ar/CActiveRecord.php:79
/Users/riverstyx/Sites/protected/tests/unit/TranslationManagerTest.php:8

FAILURES!
Tests: 2, Assertions: 0, Errors: 1
```

I understand the concept of using fixtures in Yii however I don't want to have to rely on a database to do my testing. We use MySQL in production, so creating a temporary in-memory SQLITE database seems weird because it doesn't match our actual MySQL environment and also there are some syntax nuances (ie. UTC_TIMESTAMP() doesnt exist in SQLITE).

Ideally (as with all unit tests I guess), I want to test my TranslationManager class in isolation from the active record.

Any help would be appreciated :)

Comment: Can you show the rest of your test?

Comment: Solved it!

$translation = $this->getMockBuilder("Translation")->setMethods(array("getIsNewRecord", "save"))->disableOriginalConstructor()->getMock();

disableOriginalConstructor is needed so that it doesn't call the original constructor (this was causing the problem)

also need to call setMethods and explicitly list the functions i'm overriding so that the activerecord's magic methods will still remain intact

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Figured it out...

```
$this->getMockBuilder("Translation")
     ->setMethods(array("getIsNewRecord", "save"))
     ->disableOriginalConstructor()
     ->getMock();
```

Where "Translation" is the name of my active record model. You MUST use setMethods to identify the methods you're going to be mocking so that the rest of the methods belonging to the active record will remain intact. This is important so that the default __get and __set magic methods will still work properly.

"disableOriginalConstructor" is required to properly construct the activerecord object

Comment: Yeah, doesn't help me. I still get:
`Fatal error: Call to a member function getDb() on a non-object in ..\yii2\db\ActiveRecord.php on line 135` when trying to access a property.